# How to list child items if parent is active in refinerycms?

Tags: refinerycms

I have this code to list all children of a certain page:

```
  <ul class="sidenav">
    <%= render :partial => '/refinery/menu_branch', 
      :collection => refinery_menu_pages.select{|p| p.parent_id == @page.root.id},
      :locals => {
        :hide_children => false,
        :apply_css => true 
      } -%>
  </ul>

e.g.

Item1
  cItem1
  cItem2
```

How can I modify the code to show the children of a children page?, e.g.:

```
Item1
 cItem1
 cItem2
   ccItem1
   ccItem2
   ccItem3
Item2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this code is recursive, I'm surprised it doesn't show multiple levels already. That is to say, the menu_branch partial calls the menu_branch partial until it children are nil.

Here's the code from the _menu_branch partial in RefineryCMS 2.0:

```
<%= render :partial => '/refinery/menu_branch', :collection => children,
                 :locals => {
                   :apply_css => local_assigns[:apply_css],
                   :hide_children => !!hide_children,
                   :menu_levels => local_assigns[:menu_levels]
                 } -%>
```

Notice that this one includes :menu_levels.  You could try copying and pasting that instead, or maybe just replace `local_assigns[:menu_levels]` with an integer for the number of levels you want to show.